# How to declare Types in c#

Tags: c#, class

I am not sure what is the correct name for what I am looking for!

What I am trying to do is to make a method to update a status bar text, and color it as red if it is a error message or green if it is a success message:

```
public void UpdateStatus(string message, MessageType type)
{
      if(type == MessageType.Error)
      {
           statusText.Text = message;
           statusText.ForeColor = Color.Red;
      }

      if(type == MessageType.Success)
      {
           statusText.Text = message;
           statusText.ForeColor = Color.Green;
      }
}
```

And here is the `MessageType`

```
public class MessageType
{
    class Error
    {
       //What to do here?
    }

    class Success
    {
        //What to do here?
    }
}
```

So how can I define this `MessageType` class, and how is it called? Interface? Enum? what??

Thanks.

**P.S:** I know I can just use `Color` as the second parameter for `UpdateStatus` method I wrote, but I want to learn how to make it like what I said.

Comment: Instead of a class, define `MessageType` as an [`Enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(v=VS.100).aspx).

Comment: As an aside, I usually prefer using a `switch` when working with `enum`s.  In some cases, I will also add a `default: \nthrow new NotImplementedException` in case someone modifies the `enum` (but not the function) later or casts an unmapped `int` to an `enum`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to make an [`enum` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx):

```
public enum MessageType {
    Success,
    Error
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need an `enum`:

```
public enum MessageType { Error, Success }
```

and then your `if(type == MessageType.Error)` just works.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an enum in this case:

```
public enum MessageStatus
{
  Failure,
  Success
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want an enum:

```
public enum MessageType
{
    Error,
    Success
}
```

Then in code that uses the enum you would do something like:

```
if (msg == MessageType.Error)
    // show error info
else
    // show success info
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum MessageType {Error, Success};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want an enum should be something like

```
public enum MessageType { Error, Success };
```

Take a look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(v=vs.71).aspx for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to go with the use of an enum, using:

```
public enum MessageType
{
    Failure,
    Success
}
```

... then you can handle it using a switch-case, like so:

```
public void UpdateStatus(string message, MessageType type)
{
   statusText.Text = message;

   switch (type)
   {
       case MessageType.Error:
           statusText.ForeColor = Color.Red;
           break;

      case MessageType.Success:
           statusText.ForeColor = Color.Green;
           break;
   }
}
```